# Point NGINX to Domain Name: nginx.service: Failed with result 'timeout'

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to point my Amazon EC2 instance to my sample.com domain name. The server is Django + NGINX based server. It works well with the public IP address of the server but when I add server_name example.com in my nginx config file the domain keeps loading forever.

> Mar 14 21:37:14 ip-172-31-19-81 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
> Mar 14 21:37:14 ip-172-31-19-81 systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance
> web server and a reverse proxy server.
>
> Mar 14 21:37:14 ip-172-31-19-81 systemd[1]: Starting A high
> performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
>
> Mar 14 21:37:14 ip-172-31-19-81 systemd[1]: Started A high performance
> web server and a reverse proxy server.

NGINX Config file:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/ubuntu/dir;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /api {
            include proxy_params;
            rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/dir/app.sock;

    }
    location /admin {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/dir/app.sock;
    }
    location /static {
            autoindex on;
            alias /home/ubuntu/dir/dir/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while I was deploying my website to the ec2 ubuntu server.

My mistake: I was following the blog to configure the WordPress website on ec2. I was doing copy-pasted each & everything from the blog so I also pasted the same script of configuration.

blog PHP version was old in my ubuntu server it was the latest version that's why I was getting the same error, after changing the PHP version it runs successfully.

what changes i made:  **php4.1-fpm.sock to php8.1-fpm.sock**